# Best way to put sensitive files on web server and keep them fro being accessible?

Tags: 12.04, server, permissions, filesystem

I need to put a private key on my web server for use with a php script, so I need the web server to be able to access the file in php script, but not allow users from the outside to be able to access this file.

Basically what I'm asking is where is the best place to put the file in the file system, and how do I set permissions/What are the correct permissions to set?

I have a newly setup Ubuntu 11.04 Server, and I am using the LAMP package.

Comment: If you just plant the key in the php file, that would be secure enough.

Comment: by "users from outside" you mean your site visitors who access the site using their browsers, right? Not "users" in the traditional Unix sense, i.e. people with shell access to the machine? Then putting the file outside of `/var/www` is the right solution as @Christopher suggests.

Answer (score 2):

Outside the document root. Maybe /etc/ssl/www/mykey.ext.

```
sudo mkdir -p /etc/ssl/www
sudo chown root:www-data /etc/ssl/www
sudo chmod 0750 /etc/ssl/www
sudo cp mykey.ext /etc/ssl/www/
sudo chown root:www-data /etc/ssl/www/mykey.ext
sudo chmod 0640 /etc/ssl/www/mykey.ext
```

Now it is only available to root, sudoers, and www-data. However, if Apache is configured with user dirs (~/public_html), then any user could ask Apache to read it. Or, any user that can create documents that will be read by the web server could read it.

A better solution is to read the key from a database or as a variable within the script. On the database method, protect the web application from SQL Injection.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can check editing the powerful **.htaccess** file.
http://www.javascriptkit.com/howto/htaccess.shtml
Search google for more results...